# XSLT List View Web Part

Tags: web-part, list, xlv

I cannot find XLV web part. Is it included in SharePoint 2010 by default or should be activated/added manually? What web part category should it be placed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a list through "Lists And Libraries" you actually add a XSLTListViewWebPart.
The same if you choose "Page Tools -> Insert -> Existing Lists".

It is by default scoped to current SPWeb, if you want to create a web part of it you should be able to manually create a .webpart-file that points to a specific list (even on a different SPWeb).

You can also make your own web part and aggregate it, like this:

```
var listViewWebPart = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart
    {
        ListId = myList.ID
    };
Controls.Add(listViewWebPart);
```

Comment: Many thanks! I've got another question. After i've added a list on the page (XLV wp) I can select View from list's views. But if I modify xslt for list's view it is not updated for web part view. Is it OK?

Comment: I've updated one column to be bold in the list's view. Then I opened a page added list (Page Tools -> Insert -> Existing Lists) then opened Web Part settings and selected customized view as 'Selected View'. After appying this change nothing happpened. The text in this column is not bold.

Comment: I've added another question for this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44884/customizing-xlv-web-parts-xslt